# docker unable to locate package trying to install php extension mysqli

Tags: php, docker, mysqli, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am using the [typo3-docker-boilerplate][1]

https://github.com/webdevops/TYPO3-docker-boilerplate

and trying to install a extension I need (mysqli)

I´ve tried different approach I found here and in the internet, but I always get stuck with this error message:

E: Unable to locate package mysqli

I added this into the dockerfile:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    mysqli \
    && docker-php-ext-install mysqli

RUN ln -sf /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab /etc/cron.d/docker-boilerplate \
    && chmod 0644 /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab \
    && echo >> /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab \
    && ln -sf /opt/docker/etc/php/development.ini /opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini
```

I although tried, what was written here about installing php extensions, of course without success:

https://hub.docker.com/_/php/

there is a development.ini, that will be included, which contains php instructions like:

```
post_max_size       = 50M
upload_max_filesize = 50M
max_input_vars      = 5001
```

I although tried to write this to the file

```
extension = php_mysqli.dll
```

dockerfile

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:ubuntu-16.04

ENV PROVISION_CONTEXT "development"

# Deploy scripts/configurations
COPY etc/             /opt/docker/etc/

RUN ln -sf /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab /etc/cron.d/docker-boilerplate \
    && chmod 0644 /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab \
    && echo >> /opt/docker/etc/cron/crontab \
    && ln -sf /opt/docker/etc/php/development.ini /opt/docker/etc/php/php.ini

RUN apt-get install -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install php-mysqli

#RUN apt-get update && \
#    apt-get install -y mysqli && \
#    docker-php-ext-install mysqli && \
#    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/  &&  \
#    docker-php-ext-install gd

#RUN apt-get -qq update \
#    && apt-get -qq -y install curl \
#        php-mysqli \
#    && apt-get clean -y \
#    && docker-php-ext-install php-mysqli

# Configure volume/workdir
WORKDIR /app/
```

Would be thank full for any help or suggestion.
Thanks

Comment: I don't do the apt-get at all, just the `docker-php-ext-install` line.

Comment: Why do you try to install the apt-package `mysqli`? It does not exist. What does happen if you skip it or replace the package name with `php-mysqli`?

Comment: I try this approach, because these are the examples I found about installing php extensions.
If I try this one I got this error message:
RUN apt-get install -y \
    && docker-php-ext-install php-mysqli

/bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-install: not found

Answer (score 3):

`mysqli` is a part of `php-src`. Any extension contained in `php-src` doesn't need any additional packages if you use PHP docker image. You need just to use

```
docker-php-ext-install mysqli
```

@edit
Some extensions require additional packages (e.g. iconv), anyway mysqli doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, but how do I execude this command, please?
Because this gets me the error:
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli

/bin/sh: 1: docker-php-ext-install: not found

Comment: @ToTe which image do you use as a base.

Comment: I don´t know if I can give you a good answer to that. I am quite new to docker. :)
If I type docker-compose up-d there are 3 container
app_1, mysql_1, mail_1

Comment: @ToTe include your wjhole Dockerfile content in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

apt-get install php-mysql

Once done enable mysql extension in below file

/etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

un-comment below line

extension=php_mysqli.so

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I edited my post, to give more details.